# Компилятор для Java

Tags: java, netbeans, компилятор

Доброго времени суток. Начал недавно изучать Джаву. Мне посоветовали скачать NetBeans. Скачал полную версию (200 метров примерно) и установил. В некой теме здесь нашел, что для изучения *языка* эта штука не подходит. Скажите, какой есть самый простой и доступный компилятор с подсветкой ошибок кода?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компилятор - это программа, которая из кода, написанного на каком-то языке программирования, делает исполняем файл, т.е. переводит в машинный код. NetBeans - это не компилятор, а интегральная среда разработки. Ее назначение - облегчить разработку и отладку достаточно больших проектов. Для самого начала изучения языка лучше использовать программистский блокнот (естественно, не виндовский Notepad, а какой-нибудь другой, с подсветкой языка и нормальным интерфейсом; конкретно под вин сказать затрудняюсь, поскольку пишу практически исключительно под линь) и компилятор, которым компилируешь учебные программы. Хотя, в принципе, можно и IDE использовать, но это не самый лучший вариант с педагогической точки зрения, ИМХО.

Comment: Именно такой я и хочу. Кто знает, посоветуйте!

Comment: Под винду есть отличный редактор notepad++. А вообще каких-либо преимуществ в обучении при использовании редактора над полноценной IDE я не заметил - наоборот много фишек недостает. Единственное, ситуация в которой редактор предпочтительнее для обучения - это если он противопоставляется визуальным IDE. Последние конечно губят мозг.)))

Comment: Там же он идет вместе с компилятором и всё такое? :)

Comment: Вот вспомнил, как когда-то пользовался редактором SynWriter (http://www.totalcmd.net/plugring/syn2.html). Имею о нем очень хорошие воспоминания.

Для "Vendetta8247. Ну да идет. И что? Это IDE, у которой в комплекте есть компилятор. Я это написал, чтобы человек не путал, что такое компилятор и что такое IDE.

Comment: я скачал Notepad++ и прописал в нем такую штуку, которую нашел в книге К.Арнольда и Д.Гослинга:
class HelloWorld {
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 { 
 System.out.println(“Hello, world”); 
 }
 }

Как её теперь запустить?

Comment: Сначала надо прописать в переменной окружения PATH путь к компилятору javac  и к java. Если javac нету на компе, установить JavaToolKit. Чтоб прописать, в Свойствах компьютера находите пунктик Переменные среды и там пишите ;C\;\ \Programm Files\(путь куда положено). Потом запускаете терминал, заходите в папку с Вашим проектом, и javac-java.

Comment: Спасибо, уже всё погуглил :) Прошу прощения за дурацкие вопросы :) Просто интересна эта тема!

Comment: Вопросы нормальные, в самый раз...

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans - это среда разработки не только для Java, поэтому она не имеет отношение к изучению языка. Хоть и на Java я пишу редко, но когда пишу, использую Eclipse, мне эта среда больше нравится.

Answer (score -2):

Ставьте нетБинс и не заморачивайтесь.

Научится компилировать из командной строки вы всегда успеете.

Comment: Как раз наоборот. Из командной строки перейти в IDE - нет проблем, а вот наоборот...

Comment: Не думаю что с этим возникнут какие-то трудности.

Да и сама задача сомнительна. IDE может генерировать ant файл который опять же просто запускаем в командной строке и вуаля ..

Comment: Речь не о разработке приложений, а об обучении языку. Хотя в винде такая командная строка, что и касаться ее не хочется...

Comment: Вот вот. Просто лично для меня быстрее научится в IDE с автокомплитом и хелпом по методам чем в каком то блокноте, пусть и с подсветкой синтаксиса.

Comment: Ну, если ВАМ ЛИЧНО так проще, то на здоровье. Это не догма, а рекомендация.

Comment: Научится компилировать из командной строки вы всегда успеете.<br><br>
По личному опыту убежден на 100% - бред....

Comment: бред это учится писать в блокноте когда есть удобная среда разработки.

Comment: Почему сразу - бред? На IDE пересесть всегда успеете. А вот ручками поделать - такой опыт приобретается! 

P.S. Пусть каждый пишет, как ему нравится. Лишь бы не было войны.

Comment: Например ? :)

Столько флуда уже в треде и ниодного годного аргумента. Какой опыт я получу ?

я писал в mcedit писал sh файлик для компиляции и запуска приложения, но я так и не уловил какой "бесценный" опыт я получил.

Comment: То что вы не уловили не означает что вы его не получили :)

Comment: IDE (конкретно я про Eclipse) развращает будь здоров. Методы помнишь "примерно" (подставляет !), а в каком пакете класс уже совсем не помнишь.

Без нее (скажем в Emacs) только и ищешь в доках (или книжках).

Comment: > Не думаю что с этим возникнут какие-то трудности.

@shurik, дело не в трудностях, а выработке навыков. Более того, в один прекрасный день можно оказаться, к примеру, в офисе клиента с целью задеплоить приложение, что нибудь пойдет не так, подведет установленная IDE, возникнет необходимость собрать приложение из командной строки подручными средствами, причем с JNI под другую платформу. Вот тут-то и пригодятся навыки вбивания кода в Notepad++ и ScyTE вместе с умением ручного использования javac, javah, и прочих тулзов.
> и не уловил какой "бесценный" опыт я получил.

Продолжайте практиковатьс